# Is it possible to have a std::unordered_map<Class, Class> as a member of Class?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Can the `struct var` have a member `std::unordered_map<var, var>`?

Here is a code example that is not compiling because `hash<json::var>` is declared after the use of `dict json_dict = dict();`:

```
namespace json
{
    struct var;
    using dict = std::unordered_map<var, var>;

    struct var
    {
        int integer = 0;
        std::string string = "";
        dict json_dict = dict();
    }
}

namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<json::var>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const json::var& k) const
        {
            return hash<string>()(k.string);
        }
    };
}
```

Is there a solution preferably without using pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `hash<json::var>::operator()` after you define `json::var` itself:

```
namespace json
{
    struct var;
}

namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<json::var>
    {
        // just a declaration:
        std::size_t operator()(const json::var& k) const;
    };
}

namespace json
{
    using dict = std::unordered_map<var, var>;

    struct var
    {
        int integer = 0;
        std::string string = "";
        dict json_dict = dict();
    };
}

// definition: can access `json::var`'s members
std::size_t std::hash<json::var>::operator()(const json::var& k) const 
{ 
    return k.integer; 
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MNM8Do9WFK4vOjMh)

---

Unrelated, but

```
string string = "";
dict json_dict = dict();
```

is equivalent to

```
string string;
dict json_dict;
```